# sorting output by an ID within a log line

Tags: linux, sorting, session

I have a group of log files that contain session `logins` and `logouts`. I'm looking for sessions that have been open for longer than 15-20 minutes but since there are thousands of logins, the login may appear for the pages before the logout and the session will still be only minutes later. How could I group the session numbers together so I could more easily determine which sessions are the culprits?

ex of session lines:

```
2016-11-01T07:46:44 .... vim.SessionManager.login -- 52c9959b-4853-e4da-0065-f49b01356c3c


2016-11-01T07:48:23 .... vim.SessionManager.logout -- 52c9959b-4853-e4da-0065-f49b01356c3c
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could try a basic sort command

```
cat *log files* |grep "vim.SessionManager" |sort -u -k
```